# How can I generate a Report from database table? and how can I show it in page

Tags: views

I want to generate a report from values of a database table. I tried table wizard and views to generate reports. It shows it. But how I show this to a perticular Page/form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a page view, and see your report in that page.

Comment: I tried but my page cant show report.

Comment: Can you give me a export of your view?